# Email alert script on Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set up in Spreadsheet an email alert / notification when specific cells reach a desired text value.

I'm not very used to JS but I can work on existing codes to make basic changes.

This is the sample table I need to use:

[image]

Basically I need the script to run through values of cells in Column B first and then Column C and so on and look for all the cells which value is "Fail".

For those cells, I'd like to have an email sent to specific email addresses with custom text.

If it's possible, I'd like to have a single email for each column with all the cells in that column that are "Fail".

I've tried some codes but none worked, this is the one I tried putting together with some help from the website but it doesn't gets the right cells so I must have made some errors:

```
function myFunction() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  for(n=1;n<values.length;++n){
    var cellValue = values[n][2];
    var trigger = cellValue = 'Fail';
    if (trigger) {
        //MailApp.sendEmail(values[n][1], subject, message);
        Logger.log('send mail to ' + values[n][10]);
    }
  }
}
```

If someone could help I'd appreciate that a lot :)

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

The code proposed below by *ziganotschka* works perfectly.

As I asked in the comments section, is it possible to put the values from getValues or getA1Notation into a 2D array?
I would basically like to recreate the same structure of the source table, in order to then convert the array(s) into an HTML table (which is something I can do) and insert it into the Alert email; the goal is getting as a result something like this (assuming the values you see are the ones which QC is "Fail"):

[image: Array Item1]

and

[image: Array Item2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code as following:

```
function myFunction() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var allFails = '';
  var trigger = false;
  for(a=1;a<values[0].length;a++){
    for(n=0;n<values.length;n++){
      var cellValue = values[n][a];////
      if(cellValue == 'Fail'){
        trigger  = true;
        allFails+=range.getCell(n+1, a+1).getA1Notation()+',';
      }
    }
    if (trigger) {
      //MailApp.sendEmail( allFails, subject, message);
      Logger.log('cells with Fail: ' + allFails);
    }
    trigger=false;
    allFails = '';
  }
}
```

Basically

- You create a nested `for`loop to iterate both through all rows and columns (starting with `B`)
- For each column, is the value 'Failed' is detected, the email trigger will be set to true for the corresponding column, and the A1 notation of all cells in this column containing the value 'Fail' will be added to a string

I hope this helps you!

UPDATE:

To create arrays as requested in your second questions, you can modify the code as following:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  //var allFails = '';
  var trigger = false;
  for(var a=1;a<values[0].length;a++){
    eval('var ' + 'array'+a + '= [];')
    eval('array'+a+'[0]=[];')
    eval('array'+a+'[1]=[];')
    for(var n=0;n<values.length;n++){
      var cellValue = values[n][a];////
      if(cellValue == 'Fail'){
        trigger  = true;
        eval('array'+a+'[0].push("'+values[n][0]+'");')
        eval('array'+a+'[1].push("'+cellValue+'");')
      }
    } 
    if (trigger) {
      //MailApp.sendEmail( allFails, subject, message);
      Logger.log(eval('array'+a));
    }
    trigger=false;
    allFails = '';
  }
}
```

> [Eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is a Javascript function that allows you to create dynamic
>   variable names.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you for the explanation as well, always good to have a little insight :)

Comment: Good to hear! If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting / upvoting it to increase visibility for other people with similar questions.

Comment: Hi again! Do you think it's possible to put values (or A1 notation in this case) in an array instead of adding them to a string? In particular I would like to create an array that contains cells value "connected" to the "Fail" value on the cells: when the "Fail" value is detected, I would like to put the value "QC" from Column A in Column 1 of the array, A1 notation from Column B in Column 2 of the array, "Item1" from Row 1 in Row1 of the array.

Comment: Sure, creating and populating an array is also possible. I just did not quite get the layout of the array you desire. Do you want to create a separate array for each column, or one array that contains all the fails? And you want "Item1" from Row 1 in Row 1 of the array? In Column 2 I assume? What is supposed to happen with Row 1 column 1? Maybe you could provide a visualization of what you want your array(s) to look like?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Yes I know I haven't been very clear, comments don't allow to post images so I just edited the original post with a better explanation. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hey @ziganotschka thanks for your time again, this works perfectly! Thank you so much for helping me out.